# Deploying Metadata with rest resources

Tags: rest-api, metadata

As of API 43 there seems to have been some rest resources added to the metadata api. [This Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_rest_deploy.htm) Seems to be lacking the ability to tell me how they want me to send the zip package with the JSON request object. Any information would be helpful, Thanks in advance!

Comment: Agree it is very limited in details and examples on how to use them. I tried to explore saleforce-alm module (used in cli) but even that seems to be using the rest apis only to quick deploy.

Comment: Your comment led me to an answer so thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a multi-part form... Had to scour the source code of the CLI to find this out ..

---

--boundary_string

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="entity_content";
Content-Type: application/json

{
*OPTIONS*
}

--boundary_string

Content-Type: application/zip
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file";

*Zip binary data goes here.*

--boundary_string--

---

EDIT 2/5/2021: Looks like starting at v48 they added sufficient documentation to make the call.

Comment: I was searching for the same and gonna research it. Thanks for saving my tons of time.

Comment: Thanks! It looks like `application/json` content type in part with options is crucial. If not present, Salesforce returns 500 server error with `UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION`.

Comment: I am trying the same but it is not working for me. It gives 400 `HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request` . The error says, illegal request or improperly formatted request. can someone help?

Comment: It looks like salesforce has made some changes to the documentation since this was answered, what version of the api are you using?

Comment: I am using version 50

Comment: @ZachHutchins What do you mean by ZIP binary data? How do i convert Zip file to binary data. I converted it to base64 data and used it. is it correct?  please help